# ASP.NET core Web Api CORS policy and Cert

Tags: reactjs, rest, web, asp.net-web-api

i am building a project with React and asp for API, i run the api on a pc and the react on another pc within the same network and access it from the api, I'm having a problem setting my Core Policy in ASP.NET web AP, I added these pieces to my code and it worked for sometime and then suddenly stopped for no reason

```
  builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://192.168.100.35:3000");
        });
});
```

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

that goes in my program.cs file

```
  [EnableCors(origins: "http://192.168.100.35", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

and that goes in my login page

when I tend to use `mode:no-cors` in my react project it stops taking any data from the request Body it only takes data from URL,That's about the CORS problem.
There's another problem that happened for a couple of times the request actually passed the CORS policy, i get `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` whenever i try to send any data through a POST request, i don't know why does it need cert when i'm running on localhost but even when i trust the localhost cert it's the same problem. Can anybody help me understand what's going on ?

Comment: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID ` error is for SSL! Try to run your API without the SSL and on `http` and check the result!**JUST FOR TEST AND MAKE SURE ABOUT THE ERROR!!!**
---------------------------------------------------
You said that it works before! so Try Clear Your SSL State and Browser Cache

Comment: when i disable ssl the whole project seems to crash but i tried to create a new project with https disabled but i can't get through the cors policy still to test the API

Comment: Do you use dotnet 6??

Comment: yes i use the latest version